# Convergence rate of the ratio of two normal distributions?

Tags: normal-distribution, convergence, ratio

I am interested in the behaviour of  $\log \frac{\Phi(A-x)}{\Phi(B-x)}$, when ${x\rightarrow -\infty}$ and $\Phi$ is the normal cumulative distribution function, $A<B$, and $A,B\in {\mathbb R}$. It seems like this logratio converges to $0$, but I was wondering if it is possible to check the convergence rate?

Comment: What is $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @cherub Real numbers (added, with additional condition for the sake of simplicity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal CDF $\Phi(x)$ approaches 1 for $x\longrightarrow \infty$ and approaches 0 for $x\longrightarrow -\infty$.

Since the CDF is strictly monotonic $\Phi(x) < \Phi(x+\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon > 0$, the ratio $\Phi(A-x)/\Phi(B-x)$ is always smaller than 1. To determine the value of the ratio for $x\longrightarrow -\infty$, just differentiate (L'Hospital's rule) to obtain an analytical expression, from which you'll get that $$\frac{\Phi(A-x)}{\Phi(B-x)}\longrightarrow 1\quad \mathrm{for} \quad x\longrightarrow -\infty$$
So, the logarithmic value approaches 0.

Edit:
The convergence rate can be calculated from the integral description of the CDF. Take  $$\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x c*e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} dx$$
where c is just some constant ($1/\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}$) Without limiting generality, take the shifted standard normal distribution for $\Phi(A-x)$ (or $B$). The ratio is then just 
$$\frac{\Phi(A-x)}{\Phi(B-x)} = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^x c*e^{-(x-A)^2/2\sigma^2} dx}{\int_{-\infty}^x c*e^{-(x-B)^2/2\sigma^2} dx}$$
Since both have the same the same variance, most things vanish after expanding the term. Omitting the constant terms, since they're not interesting for convergence it reduces to:
$$\frac{\Phi(A-x)}{\Phi(B-x)} = \beta e^{-\alpha x(B-A)}$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are some constants.
When you take the logarithm of the ratio, you'll get a linear term. Ergo the convergence is linear.

Comment: @Xi'an: thanks for the edit; my name memory is terrible. But de l'Hospital is of course right.

Comment: @cherub My friend George Casella used to say that L'Hospital's rule was the first trick he tried!

Comment: The convergence rate is rather easy to establish, because $\Phi$ *does* have a useful analytic expression as an integral.  You could exploit Mill's Ratio, for instance, to show that the log of the ratio diverges quadratically in $x$ for all $A\ne B.$

Comment: @whuber: you're right with the integral expression. But if I do the calculation then I get the expression $c**\frac{B}{A}\exp(-x/(2\sigma^2)*(B-A))$ for the direct ratio. If I take the log, then this is linear. Obviously I mixed something up in recalling. But I don't get quadratic convergence.

Comment: Sorry; you're right: I had in mind the case where the two standard deviations differ.  When they're the same, the $x^2$ terms in the exponent cancel, leaving a linear term.

Comment: I'll update the answer to include this explanation, thanks for replying.